# Change Cursor on Mouse Over for all Controls and their Childs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with so many controls in it. Currently I have set a cursor for my form:

```
this.Cursor = TargetCursor;
```

This cursor will be the default cursor for every control. But I need to change Cursor on mouse over of every control. 
How Can I do this without managing mouse over event for every control?

Comment: Take a step back and ask yourself if this is sane and useful UI design.  What are you trying to tell the user?  How is the control going to behave differently just because the mouse is hovering over it?  If you don't want to "manage the mouse" then nothing different *could* happen so changing the cursor is not useful at all.

Comment: When designing is important, Changing and Setting a beautiful cursor will be important too and makes application's looking better.

Comment: So just change the default cursor and make it "beautiful".  Changing the shape performs an important function, it tells the user that the mouse no longer has default behavior.  Like the I-bar in a TextBox, now it also selects text.  Or the arrows on the window edges, now it also resizes the window.  Getting non-default behavior from the mouse requires subscribing events.  You actually really do have to "manage the mouse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all controls and change their `Cursor` property. Like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
       control.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;                
    }
}
```

And to support multi level controls and controls inside containers you can use a recursive method like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    setCursor(Controls);
}

void setCursor(IEnumerable theControls)
{
     foreach (Control control in theControls)
     {
         if (control.HasChildren)
         {
              setCursor(control.Controls);
         }
         else
             control.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Stranger ... I'm wondering why my answer should get downvote! Based on your question you said *This cursor will be the default cursor for every control. But I need to change Cursor on mouse over of every control.* my answer should exactly be what you want if you test it. I'd also appreciate an explanation from the downvoter, If I'm incorrect, I'd like to know how.

Comment: (did not downvote), but have to mention that you are only setting the first level controls, but not for controls inside containers (e.g. `GroupBox`, `TabControl`, `Panel` etc)

Comment: @Stranger ... I know you are not downvoter. I just said did you test this answer ever?

Comment: @user2946329 as I told, changing form's cursor will do what you mentioned.

Comment: @Stranger .. But changing form's cursor will always show the cursor with mouse over and leave. But my code just show the cursor on controls and only when **Mouse Over**!!

Comment: @Stranger please read the code in this answer. user2946329 is *not* setting the Form's Cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all controls are in one specific panel called `pnlMain`, you can use a recursive method to do it all for you.

```
private void ChangeCursor(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control con in control.Controls)
    {
        con.MouseHover += con_MouseHover;
        ChangeCursor(con);
    }
}

void con_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ct = (Control) sender;
    ct.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
ChangeCursor(pnlMain);
```

You could also add event handler for `MouseLeave` to reset the cursor if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a global solution that will work for all Controls without accessing each Control. So this would be a recursive method to set the Cursor for all Controls:

```
void SetCursorOnControls(Control parent, Cursor cursor)
{
    parent.Cursor = cursor;
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
        SetCursorOnControls(c, cursor);
}
```

Maybe you'll need a `try...catch` block around `parent.Cursor = cursor` since you may iterate into composite controls and find child controls that won't support the `Cursor` property (I don't think they will through, but I'm not sure).

If you explicitly want to do it only on Mouse events, try that:

```
void SetCursorEventsOnControls(Control parent, Cursor cursor)
{
    parent.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => ((Control)sender).Cursor = cursor;
    parent.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => ((Control)sender).Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
        SetCursorOnControls(c, cursor);
}
```

With respect to user2946329's answer/comments, you should call these methods as this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    foreach(Control c in Controls)
       SetCursorOnControls(c, Cursors.Hand); // or SetCursorEventsOnControls
}
```

So you won't set the Cursor of your Form.